# htaccess language redirect when any language set

Tags: regex, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website example.com, the default locale is English, I want to redirected to example.com/en If is not set a language.

All request without language argument should redirect to default language

sample :

```
example.com/blogpost/thisisapost
```

should redirect to :

```
example.com/en/blogpost/thisisapost
```

or

```
example.com/one/tow/three/etc
```

should redirect to :

```
example.com/en/one/tow/three/etc
```

The website Developed with Laravel.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please post your attempted htaccess rules file in your question.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. Link example.com/en/one/tow/three/etc should be served by which file in backend?

Comment: No,Just focus on redirecting , it is only example, all links without language argument should redirect to default language . @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 0):

You can create the redirect like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
rewriteRule ^/?(^((?!nl|en).)*$) https://example.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`en` and `nl` will not be matched now, but everything else will

You can see the result [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=ae057a47-23cf-4021-b83f-30c6697cdee2)

Comment: I added some description in my question

Comment: @RizaGulizade I saw and edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line to make it work:

```bash
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule !^[a-z]{2}/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

**Explanation:**

- `!^[a-z]{2}/` is negative condition that succeeds when URI doesn't start with 2 lowercase letters followed by `/`
- `/en%{REQUEST_URI}` prepends `REQUEST_URI` with `/en` so that we get `/en` as default language in URLs
- `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` is a condition that checks for empty value of `REDIRECT_STATUS` variable to make sure this rule doesn't fire after an internal rewrite.